# Dictionary WebService DictService.asmx code doesn't work in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I'm trying to compile and run the following code in Eclipse, but it doesn't work. The goal is to make a request on the dictionary web service http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL with the certain word and get the definition of this word back to the user. Could you please help to fix it. I think that some plugins are missing, because it shows errors near the import statements.

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath.*;
import com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.element.Node;

// RestAssured source: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/1.6/com/jayway/restassured/RestAssured.java#RestAssured
//  URL: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx/Define?word=string
// WSDL: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL

public class RATest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    baseURI = "http://services.aonaware.com";
    port = 80;      
    String defCandidate = "fastidious";
    String xml = get("/DictService/DictService.asmx/Define?word=" + defCandidate ).andReturn().asString();

    int items = from(xml).get("WordDefinition.Definitions.Definition.size()");
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("Number of definitions returned: " + items);

    for( int i=0; i<items ; i++ ) {
      int defNum = i + 1;
      Node def = from(xml).get("WordDefinition.Definitions.Definition[" + i + "]");
      String returnedWord = def.getNode("Word").value();
      String dictName = def.getNode("Dictionary").getNode("Name").value();
      String definition = def.getNode("WordDefinition").value();
      System.out.println("Definition " + defNum + ": ");
      System.out.println("Word: " + returnedWord );
      System.out.println("Dictionary: " + dictName );
      System.out.println("Definition: " + definition );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please include the errors in your question

Comment: the first and i think the main one is : the import com.jayway can't be resolved